# SQL : Append two queries with same "GROUP BY ORDER BY" and same number of rows

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have the following query :

```
SELECT q2.name, q1.countParticipants, q2.countGames FROM 
(
    SELECT c.countryName AS name,  count(p.idParticipant) AS countParticipants 
    FROM Country c, Participant p, Game g 
    WHERE p.fkGame = g.idGame AND c.idCountry = p.fkCOuntry AND c.countryName LIKE '%$countryName%' 
    GROUP BY c.countryName 
    ORDER BY c.countryName;
) AS q1 ,
(
    SELECT c.countryName AS name, count(g.idGame) as countGames 
    FROM Country c, Game g 
    WHERE c.idCountry = g.fkHostCountry AND c.countryName LIKE '%$countryName%' GROUP BY c.countryName 
    ORDER BY c.countryName)
) AS q2 
GROUP BY q1.name 
ORDER BY q1.name
```

The query is supposed to return the number of participants at the Olympic Games that took place in a given `countryName` (q1) as well as the number of **total** games that took place in the same `countryName` (q2). It does return something, but the result is wrong.

Instead of returning what I need (i.e. the **total** number of games), it seems to return the number of games that the `participants`in `countParticipants` participated to (for the given country).

Now, either the problem comes form the data in my DB, either from my query. Can you please check it out so I know where to correct the issue ?

Thank you very much

**NOTE** : The resultSet of both ot the subqueries return the same number of rows and are ordered the same way.

Comment: Do you know what `GROUP BY` does?

Comment: Yes I know what it does. I have more of an intermediate SQL level :)

Comment: You need an aggregate to use it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need any relation between tables q1 and q2?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: @eternay No, because in the second query I dont not link the Participant table as I want the total number of games

Comment: [`GROUP BY` Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Is it the GROUPING_SET I should look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using one query and the use of `COUNT(DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT  c.countryName AS name, 
        COUNT(p.idParticipant) AS countParticipants ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT g.idGame) AS CountGames
FROM    Country c
        INNER JOIN Participant p
            ON c.idCountry = p.fkCOuntry
        INNER JOIN Game g 
            ON p.fkGame = g.idGame
WHERE   c.countryName LIKE '%$countryName%' 
GROUP BY c.countryName 
ORDER BY c.countryName;
```

If you are wondering why I have changed your implicit ANSI 89 joins to explicit ANSI 92 joins give [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) a read. Although ANSI 89 joins are not wrong, and normally create the same execution plans, I beleive the reasons to use them are out weighed by the reasons not to use them.

Comment: Nice! Thanks :) I didn't know the trick about the joins. The article seems interesting as well ü

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a nice aggregate function called rollup, which subtotals based on the columns passed to it.

Here is a link to some examples of rollup:

http://www.compshack.com/sql/oracle-group-rollup